# iPhone: jQuery scroll() event only fires on release

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I noticed that on the iPhone, the scroll event only fires after I finish scrolling. Is there a way to detect the start of a scroll?

Comment: no that ios5 has solved the position fixed issue, i would expect to work...did you find the solution?

Comment: Just a little update here: It's almost 2 years later and the position Fixed is still buggy on iOS6.
http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

I love apple products, but I think this is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) confirms this issue. Would binding to ontouchmove work for you?

Comment: touchmove is the same as javascript onscroll for iphone 4. It doesn't always feedback the value only on release.